# list instead of list of list

Tags: python, list

I have this code that returns a list of list, I would like to return only one list efficiently, how can I achieve that?

```
def GetCast(path,key,Ids):
    list=[]
    for n in Ids:
        l=requests.get(path + str(n) + '/credits',key )
        data= l.json()
        cast_Ids= [i['name'] for i in data['cast']]
        list.append(cast_Ids)
    return list
```

Comment: whoever downvote this, why u did this?

Comment: people have their reasons to downvote. One being: downvoting questions is free.

Comment: if affects who is asking the question badly

Comment: it's a useful and required mechanism. Note that everyone is free to counter the downvote. Don't take it too hard. One on my (meta) questions started with 2 downvotes, and skyrocketted at 150+ votes. if it weren't for downvotes, we couldn't tell trolls to get lost for instance.

Comment: another reason could be: it's a borderline basic & duplicate question. That's why I have added the list comprehension rewrite to add more value (I almost just commented "use `extend` instead" but I had some discussion about "don't answer in comments" recently)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change

```
list.append(cast_Ids)
```

by

```
list.extend(cast_Ids)  # variant: list += cast_Ids
```

(and don't use `list` from now on as it's the builtin name for the list type)

or in one line with flattening list comprehension (I haven't tested this, and it's not particularly easy to read):

```
lst = [i['name'] for n in Ids for i in requests.get(path + str(n) + '/credits',key ).json()['cast']]
```

Comment: is there anyway the code can be more efficient, What you mentioned at the end can be shorter and complicated to read, but it's not faster

Comment: It seems to rely heavily on the response time of `requests.get` call, so probably not.